# Is it "to shave my beard" or "to shave my face"?

Tags: word-choice

> I shaved my beard this morning.
>   I shaved my face this morning.

Which one is the correct sentence?

Comment: By "bear", do you mean "beard"? I'm just kidding. :)

Comment: Um… do you mean *beard*, not *bear*?  Or do you enjoy keeping dangerous pets as a hobby?

Comment: I really have a bear I shave all the weekends, but as it seems there are WWF associates, let's change the question. ;-)

Comment: @kiamaluno: in that case the answer would be “well, which one did you shave this morning: the bear, or your face”?  :-)

Comment: Thanks for changing, *bear* has a rather NSFW connotation for native German speakers. (^_^)

Comment: Bär & Bärtchen. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are both reasonable sentences; they mean slightly different things.  But the most common and idiomatic thing to say would be simply

> I shaved this morning.

If you are male, then unless context explicitly suggests otherwise, this will be taken to mean that you shaved your face.  (If you’re female, then legs and/or armpits will probably be the default interpretation.)

> I shaved my face this morning.

means essentially the same, and is a bit less idiomatic, but would be used to clarify the meaning if context could suggest shaving something else — if, for instance, you also regularly shave your head, then you might want to use this one.

> I shaved my beard this morning.

is again less common, and more specific.  You would be more likely to use this if you sometimes grow a significant beard, and less likely to use it if you shave every day.

Answer (score 2):

First, That's beard.

Second, you can use both.

See the Examples:

> I wish he'd **shave off** that awful **beard**.
>
> I've decided to **shave off** my **beard**.

And for face:

> Before using the device, you should learn how to **shave your face**.

Answer (score 1):

You shave **off** a beard.

You shave your face.

That is the simple difference.

Comment: that was my first reaction too, but apparently that distinction isn’t as consistent as I thought; looking around on the internet reveals that plenty of people use the phrasing “shave [my/your/etc.] beard” — going by google hits, it’s only slightly less common than “shave off [my/your/…] beard”.  Although I will definitely agree: you do not “shave off your face”! :-)